# How to add next and previous buttons in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, user-interface

We create a matlab gui for registration.In that form we have to see each images from an array on the buttons clicks. we need to be implement two pushbuttons ie 'next' and 'previous'. when we click previous we have to see previous image on the axis and vice versa. plz help us. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. we are using guide with two pushbuttons ie next and previous.

Comment: and what are the callback functions you associated with these pushbuttons?

Comment: Where the array of images is located in memory? Or is it not loaded in memory yet?

Comment: when press pushbuttton for next, we have to see the image in the array or a folder. That folder contains  images. we have to load each one on button click. we are new in matlab plz help. @Shai

Comment: @CST-Link now we add a browse button to select images from an exciting folder. We have to implement array.

Comment: look into [`uigetfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html). [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) can also help. store images in a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the steps are pretty straightforward:

1. In your GUI's `OpeningFcn` you should add code to load the images from the folder:

   - create a cell array filed in `handles`, e.g. `handles.img_store`;
   - load images one by one in `handles.img_store{:}` using `imread()`;
   - create a current image index, e.g. `handles.img_index`, and initialize it to 1;
   - display the current image using `display_current_image()` function—see 4.;
2. Write the callback for the pushbutton "Next" to increment `handles.img_index`, reset it to previous value if it goes out of bounds of `handles.img_store`, then call `display_current_image()`—see 4.;
3. Write the callback for the pushbutton "Previous" to decrement `handles.img_index`, reset it to previous value if it goes out of bounds of `handles.img_store`, then call `display_current_image()` function—see 4.;
4. Create a function, e.g. `display_current_image()` that will take `handles` as argument and, using the `image()` function, displays the image with the index `handles.img_index` in the cell array `handles.img_store`

I will not write code, not until you try to write some code first. :-)